# Find the conditional expectation $E(X|aX+bY)$ $X$ and $Y$ are correlated normal random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

let $(X,Y)$ is a bivariate normal random variable with $\mathbb  E(X)=\mu_1$,$\text{ Var}(X)=\sigma_1^2$,
$\mathbb E(Y)=\mu_2$,$\text{ Var}(Y)=\sigma_2^2$ and $\rho(X,Y)=\rho$($\rho$ is the correlation function ).
I want to find Find the conditional expectation  $\mathbb E(X\mid aX+bY)$ 
and  know the following calculations is correct or no?
The question is: Is the calculation  correct?

The importance of this question is all of following question are special case of this so we can answer it easily use the results of this question. 
[$\color{red}{1)}\mathbb E( cX + dY | aX + bY = u), \text{i.i.d case}$here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213067/bivariate-normal-conditional-expectation) ,
[$\color{red}{2)}\mathbb E(X \, |  \, 3X + 4Y],\text{i.i.d case}$here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597252/conditional-expectation-of-normal-random-variables)
[$\color{red}{3)}\mathbb{E}(X-Y \mid 2X+Y),\text{correlated case}$here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3590203/calculate-mathbbex-y-mid-2xy-if-x-sim-n0-a-and-y-sim-n0-b/3590505#3590505)
[$\color{red}{4)}\mathbb{E}(X\mid X+Y),\text{i.i.d case}$here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606166/finding-mathbbex-mid-xy-for-independent-normal-variables-x-y/3606370#3606370)
[$\color{red}{5)}\mathbb{E}(3X+Y|X-Y=1),\text{correlated case}$here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912909/conditional-expectation-of-linear-combination-of-normal-random-variable)
[$\color{red}{6)}\mathbb{E}(X\mid 2X + Y),\text{i.i.d case}$here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225031/find-expectation-of-conditional-random-variables)
[$\color{red}{7)}\mathbb E(2X+Y|X-Y=1),\text{i.i.d case}$here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2952132/conditional-expectation-of-e2xyx-y-1)

I want to find $d$ such that $\text{cou}(X-dY, aX+bY)=0$ and by [Correlations_and_independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence) conclude $X-dY$ and $aX+bY$ are independent.

$$0=\text{cou}(X-dY, aX+bY)=a\text{Var}(X)-db \text{Var}(Y)+(b-ad) \text{cou}(X,Y)=a\sigma_1^2-db\sigma_2^2 +(b-ad) \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2=(a\sigma_1^2 +b \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2)
-d(b\sigma_2^2+a \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2)$$ so
 $d=\frac{a\sigma_1^2 +b \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2}{b\sigma_2^2+a \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2}$

So I want to use following properties
\begin{eqnarray}
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\mathbb E(aX+bY\mid aX+bY) =aX+bY      \\
\mathbb E(X-dY \mid aX+bY) = \mathbb E(X-dY)=\mu_1 -d \mu_2       
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}
and find $E(X|aX+bY)$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
a\mathbb E(X \mid aX+bY)+b\mathbb E(Y\mid aX+bY) =aX+bY      \\
\mathbb E(X \mid aX+bY)-d \mathbb E(Y \mid aX+bY)=\mu_1 -d \mu_2         
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\mathbb E(Y \mid aX+bY) &=&\frac{(aX+bY)-a(\mu_1 -d \mu_2)}{b+ad}      \\
\mathbb E(X \mid aX+bY) &=&\frac{(aX+bY)+\frac{b}{d}(\mu_1 -d \mu_2)}{a+\frac{b}{d}}   
=  \frac{d(aX+bY)+b(\mu_1 -d \mu_2)}{b+ad}    
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}

$$\mathbb E(X\mid aX+bY)=\frac{a\sigma_1^2+b \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2}{
a^2 \sigma_1^2+b^2 \sigma_2^2 +2ab\sigma_1 \sigma_2}(aX+bY)+\frac{b^2 \sigma_2^2 +2ab\sigma_1 \sigma_2}{
a^2 \sigma_1^2+b^2 \sigma_2^2 +2ab\sigma_1 \sigma_2}(\mu_1 -\frac{a\sigma_1^2 +b \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2}{b\sigma_2^2+a \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2} \mu_2)$$

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide

Comment: So what's your question? If you want to answer your own question, please consider posting it as a community wiki.

Comment: @Saad. Thanks for attention,you right, It is done now.