# Let $(X,Y)$ be a Gaussian random vector with given means, variances and correlation, determine $E[X\mid X+Y]$ and $E[X\mid Y]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Let $(X,Y)$ be a Gaussian random vector, with $E[X]=E[Y]=0$, $var(X)=\sigma^2,\ var(Y)=\tau^2$, and $Cor(X,Y)=\rho$ (correlation coefficient). Find $E[X\mid X+Y]$ and $E[X\mid Y]$.

My attempt for $E[X\mid X+Y]$ is to first write
$$E[X\mid X+Y]+E[Y\mid X+Y]=E[X+Y\mid X+Y]=X+Y$$
Since $(X,Y)$ is a Gaussian vector, $X+Y$ is also Gaussian. We can compute that $E[X+Y]=0$ and $var(X+Y)=\tau^2+\sigma^2+2\sigma\tau\rho$. Therefore, $X+Y\sim N(0,\tau^2+\sigma^2+2\sigma\tau\rho)$. But after this I don't know how to continue.

Another problem is that this does not seem to work for $E[X\mid Y]$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649825/find-the-conditional-expectation-exaxby-x-and-y-are-correlated-normal  $\mathbb E(X\mid aX+bY)=\frac{a\sigma_1^2+b \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2}{
a^2 \sigma_1^2+b^2 \sigma_2^2 +2ab\sigma_1 \sigma_2}(aX+bY)+\frac{b^2 \sigma_2^2 +2ab\sigma_1 \sigma_2}{
a^2 \sigma_1^2+b^2 \sigma_2^2 +2ab\sigma_1 \sigma_2}(\mu_1 -\frac{a\sigma_1^2 +b \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2}{b\sigma_2^2+a \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2} \mu_2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: Let $Z=cX+Y$ where $c$ is chosen such that $cov (X+Y,Z)=0$. (Compute $c$ by expanding the covariance). Then express $X$ as $t(X+Y)+sZ$. This means $X=(t+s)X+(t+sc)Y$ so we can take $s=\frac 1  {c-1}$ and $t= \frac 1 {1-c}$. Now note that $Z$ and $X+Y$ are independent (by joint normality) and $E(X|X+Y)=E(t(X+Y)+sZ|X+Y)=t(X+Y)+EZ=t(X+Y)$. [I will let you find out what you can do when $c=1$].

A similar argument can be used for $E(X|Y)$: Choose $d$ such that $X+dY$ is independent of $Y$. (You only have to make their covariance $0$). Then $E(X|Y)=E((X+dY)-dY|Y)==E(X+dY)-dY=-dY$.

Comment: If $c=0$, then $X+Y$ would have variance $0$ and thus must be a.s. constant. But since $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Gaussian, $X+Y$ must be a Gaussian r.v. as well. The contradiction would imply $c\neq1$. Am I right?

Comment: @trisct If $X+Y$ is a constant  then $E(X|X+Y)=EX=0$ by independence. When you say that linear combinations of jointly Guassian random variables are Guassian  you have consider constants also as (degenerate) Guassian so you cannot say that $X+Y$ being a constant is  a contradiction.

Comment: I see. My original idea of what "jointly Gaussian" is was wrong. Does this mean if $X\sim N(m,\sigma^2)$, then $X$ is jointly Gaussian with itself? And, just to be sure, Gaussian vector and jointly Gaussian mean the same thing, right?

Comment: Yes,  $X_1,..X_n$ are jointly Gaussian  iff $(X_1,..X_n)$ is a Gaussian vector. And $(X,X)$ is also Gaussian; it has a degenerate Gaussian distribution.  @trisct

Comment: Just to clarify, a useful characterization of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ being jointly Gaussian (i.e. $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ being a Gaussian vector) is that $\alpha_1 X_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n X_n$ is a univariate Gaussian for all $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n ) \in \mathbb{R}^n.$ This characterization makes it easy to see e.g. that $Z$ and $X+Y$ are jointly Guassian because a linear combination of them is also a linear combination of $X$ and $Y,$ which is univariate Gaussian since $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Gaussian.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you know of a similar trick to compute $E(X|X+Y > 0)$ ?

Comment: @RagibZaman Unfortunately the trick I used in my answer does not work here..

Answer (score 1):

$X|Y$ is also gaussian random variable.This is because Gaussian Conditional Property.This holds In general for any finite dimensional gaussian random vectors. Look up for derivations because they are a bit tedious and i am just stating $2D$ result here.You can find the general result here. [MVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)

$$\begin{pmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N} \left( \begin{pmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} \sigma^2_1 & \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \\ \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2 & \sigma^2_2 \end{pmatrix} \right) $$

The conditional expectation of X1 given X2 is:

$$\operatorname{E}(X_1 \mid X_2=x_2) = \mu_1 + \rho \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}(x_2 - \mu_2) =$$

In your case it reduces to following

$$\operatorname{E}[X|Y=y] = \rho \frac{\sigma}{\tau}.y$$