# What is the conditional expectation of random variables X given Y if X and Y are correlated?

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, correlation

Lots of answers online on what is $E[X|Y]$ if $X$ is independent of $Y$ (that would imply $E[X|Y] = E[X]$).

However, what if the correlation of $X$ and $Y$ is not zero? To work with actual values, what is $E[X|Y]$ if:

- $X$ is normally distributed as $N(\mu_X=2,\sigma_X^2=3)$
- $Y$ is normally distributed as $N(\mu_X=0,\sigma_Y^2=1)$
- $corr(X,Y)=\rho$ (some number between $-1$ and $1$, but not necessarily $0$)

Comment: You have to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal. Otherwise you cannot determine $E(X|Y)$.

Comment: And if we do indeed assume that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal? How could we still determine $E(X|Y)$?

Comment: Ah, I see that the formula for $E(X|Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal is given here (page 4): http://home.iitk.ac.in/~zeeshan/pdf/The%20Bivariate%20Normal%20Distribution.pdf

Comment: I think this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649825/find-the-conditional-expectation-exaxby-x-and-y-are-correlated-normal may help you. Just set $a=0$ and $b=1$. You can also find conditional distribution $X|Y=y$, which is normal too.