# What is $E[X | X + Y]$ if $X, Y$ are independent normal RVs?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am confused by this question. If $X, Y$ are exchangeable and the question instead asked for $E[X | X + Y = c]$ for some constant $c$, then $E[X | X + Y = c] = c / 2$ regardless of whether $X, Y$ are independent and their individual distributions.

But the question is asking for $E[X | X + Y]$, which is a random variable. How does knowing that $X, Y$ are independent normal help?

Comment: $E[X | X + Y]$ is the orthogonal projection of $X$ onto the line spanned by $X+Y$.  So perhaps start by computing the angle between $X$ and $X+Y$.

Comment: If $X,Y$ are independent normal then $X$ given $X+Y$ also has a normal distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, I understand, but how does that help with finding E[X | X + Y]

Comment: It is the mean of this conditional distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I'm still confused how $E[X | X+Y]$ isn't a random variable. When we talk about law of iterated expectations, $E[X | Y]$ is a random variable. Doesn't the same idea apply in this case?

Comment: It *is* a random variable. For $T=X+Y$, if $g(t)=E[X\mid T=t]$ then what you are looking for is the random variable $g(T)=E[X\mid T]$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Ah I see. What does the pdf $f_{X | Z}$ look like where $Z = X + Y$? We know that $Z \sim N(\mu_X + \mu_Y, \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2)$, but I don't see how this helps.

Comment: I think this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649825/find-the-conditional-expectation-exaxby-x-and-y-are-correlated-normal may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal and this implies that $X-aY$ and $X+Y$ are jointly normal too for any real number $a$. So $X-aY$ and $X+Y$ are independent if their covariance is $0$. Choose $a$ such that the covariance is $0$ [If there is no such $a$ there would be $a$ such that $Y-aX$ and $X+Y$ are independent and the proof is similar in this case].  If it so happens that $a=-1$ then $X+Y$ is independent of itself and this forces $X$ and $Y$ to be constants since $X$ and $Y$ are also given to be independent. So $1+a \neq 0$. Now $X=\frac 1 {1+a} (X-aY)+ \frac a {1+a} (X+Y)$. Now it is easy to calculate the conditional expectation.

Alternative solution:

A well known result is the following:

If $X,X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are jointly normal then $E(X|X_1,X_2,....,X_n)$ is  a linear combination of $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$.

Using this $E(X|X+Y)=c(X+Y)$ for some constant $c$ and we get $c$ from the fact that $E(X(X+Y))=cE(X+Y)^{2}$,

Comment: I'm going to parse this from the beginning. It's a little over my head right now. But to clarify, jointly normal and bivariate normal here mean the same thing right?

Comment: Yes, they mean they same thing. @student010101

Comment: Why does $a = -1$ mean $cov(X + Y, X+Y) = 0$?

$$
cov(X - aY, X + Y) = cov(X, X) - a cov(Y, Y) - acov(X, Y) + cov(X, Y) \\
= cov(X, X) - a cov(Y, Y)
$$

if $a = -1$, then

$$
cov(X + Y, X + Y) = cov(X, X) + cov(Y, Y)  \\
= var(X) + var(Y) 
$$

How does $var(X) + var(Y) = 0$? This would require $var(X) = var(Y) = 0$ which would mean X and Y are constant.

Comment: @student010101 I have added some more details for my answer.

Comment: I don't think the edits explains why $a = -1 \implies cov(X+Y, X+Y) = 0$? Am I misunderstanding/missing something?

Comment: I am choosing $a$ such that $cov(X-aY,X+Y)=0$. If this $a$ happens to be $-1$ then $cov(X+Y,X+Y)=0$: just put $a=-1$. @student010101

Comment: Right, I understand that you are choosing $a$ to get the zero covariance between $X - aY, X+Y$, but what I don't is why $a = -1$ gives $cov(X + Y, X + Y) = 0$. In order to have this equality, doesn't it require $var(X) = var(Y) = 0$?

Comment: @student010101 $cov(X+Y,X+Y)=0$ means $var (X+Y)=0$ which means $X+Y$ is a constant. If $X+Y=c$ then $X=c-Y$ and $X$ and $Y$ are indepednent. So  $X$ and $c-Y$ are  independent  so $X$ is independent of itself, so $X$ is  a constant. So is $Y$. I this case you don't have  a problem with $EX|X+Y)$ right?

Comment: Ahh. I was thinking about this backwards. In this case I would be able to compute the expectation. But I don't understand what part of the original problem told us to go down this route that you did. Was it just an assumption you made?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume X,Y are i.i.d (otherwise just do some linear transformation).
By symmetry $E(X| X+Y) = E(Y| X+Y) $.
And by linearity, $E(X| X+Y) + E(Y| X+Y)=E(X+Y|X+Y)$, So $E(X|X+Y)=(X+Y)/2$.